# How to create a column for p-values grouped by variable

Tags: r

I am working with a large data frame of clinical information. It includes info on several cell types, cell counts, and treatment response for a large group of patients. I want to plot each individual cell type into a box plot comparing cell counts for positive vs negative response:
[this is an example of what I want][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHvda.png

Because of the size of the data frame, I want to filter the data so that I only create box plots that show significance.
I decided that the best way to do this was to create a column for p-values and use the p-values assigned to filter the data frame.

I tried the following:

```
# zb is the orginal data frame
zb.pval <- zb %>%
  group_by(cell_type) %>%
  mutate(res.ct.pval = kruskal.test(response ~ count)$p.value)
```

However, I get an error:

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `res.ct.pval`. x all observations are in the same group i Input `res.ct.pval` is `kruskal.test(response ~ count)$p.value`. i The error occured in group 30: cell_type = "ACTIVATION HLA DR FITC- CD69 PE- CD19 ECD- CD56 PC5.5- CD16 PC7+ CD134 APC+ CD4 700+ CD3 750- CD8 750+".

I decided to try a for loop:

```
pval.list <- list()
for(ct in pval.list){
tmp <- zb %>% 
filter(cell_type == ct)
pval.list[[ct]] <- kruskal.test(tmp$response ~ tmp$count)$p.value
}
pval.df <- pval.list %>% 
bind_rows() %>% 
rownames_to_column(var = "cell_type")
```

But I just end up with an empty data frame. I do not have a ton of experience with r and am wondering if I am making any obvious mistakes. Otherwise, I am curious if anyone has a better way of doing this.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example  with `dput` for testing.  thank you

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. I think it is more likely to be your data problem. You might have some comparisons with only one group or no observations. If you provide a reproducible example, it would be easy for others to help you.

Comment: Hi @mun9, welcome to StackOverflow! If you can post a reproducible example that will help others try to answer as well. Can you do dput(head(df,10)) (where df is the name of your dataframe and replace 10 with the number of lines of your dataframe you want to include?